# Camunda Mocking Function Calls in Script Task

Tags: bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

I have a script task in a camunda project that uses some scripting.

I'm trying to figure out how I could verify`test.isObject()` has been called in my unit test.

I know `verify(testOrder,times(1)).isObject();` can be used, but I don't know how I can mock the `testObject` ?

```
<bpmn:scriptTask id="test" name="test" scriptFormat="JavaScript" camunda:resultVariable="testVariable">
<bpmn:script>
  <script>
    var testObject = execution.getVariable("testObject");
    if(! testObject.isObject()){
        throw "Error in test object";

    }
  </bpmn:script>
</scriptTask>
```